# What GUI framework or libs are used in Unreal Engine 4 Feature Demo?

Tags: user-interface, unreal-development-kit

Unreal Engine 4 GUI like this:
https://pcper.com/2012/06/e3-12-unreal-engine-4-what-you-and-we-missed-at-gdc/

Unreal Engine 3 use wxwidgets，but in UE4 it looks like .NET Framework WPF. The GUI in UE4 is fantastic.

P.S. Microsoft Expression Studio 4 has the same style.

Comment: I currently also wan't to know this...

Comment: I think they are using WPF

Answer (score 5):

it is not wxwidgets and wpf.
it is a new gui framework which is developed by unreal engine 4 team and it named "Slate UI Framework".
this framework used for editor and game twice, so it is a cross platform framework and use hardware accerlation, like unity3D editor.
if you use some software for example Fraps, it will tell you the full screen is one frame buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The Unreal Engine 3, at least later builds of it are slowly replacing wxWidgets with WPF which you can tell by looking at some of the .NET .dll files and also by the look of the Content Browser, color picker etcetera.

It would make sense for the Unreal Engine 4 to continue that trend.

Answer (score 1):

The UE4 Editor utilizes the Slate UI Framework for its widgets.

They can be inspected via the Widget Reflector tool, which allows selecting a widget currently present on the editor screen and then finding and inspecting, among other aspects, its source code, like so:

- In UE4, go to `Window > Developer Tools > Widget Reflector`
- In the Widget Reflector window, click `Pick Hit-Testable Widgets` or `Pick Painted Widget`
- Move the mouse over any widget on the editor window and press `ESC` to stop
- Notice that the widget and its corresponding CPP file will be highlighted in the Widget Reflector

On a default installation of UE4, the base folder containing Slate UI widgets should be:

`C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Source\Runtime\Slate\`

For instance, the implementation of the `SBox` widget can be found at:

`C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Source\Runtime\Slate\Private\Widgets\Layout\SBox.cpp`

Aside from being utilized to build the UE4 Editor itself, the Slate UI Framework can also [be utilized in games/content created with it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeK6DPB5weA).

This [document](https://dokumen.tips/documents/the-slate-ui-framework.html) provides an overview of the framework by its creator.